# MySQL: Obtener tabla con intervalos 30minutales a partir de otra con fechas

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla que consta de tres campos fecha con formato YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS: **in**, **out** y **near**. Si existe **in** también ha de existir **out**, y ambas dos pueden ir acompañadas o no de **near**; **near** puede existir por sí sola. No cabe la posibilidad de que las tres sean `NULL`; por ejemplo:

```
in_time             out_time            near_time
2019-10-02 10:46:31 2019-10-02 12:34:43 2019-10-02 09:51:57
NULL                NULL                2019-10-02 11:51:08
2019-10-02 12:02:40 2019-10-02 12:08:56 NULL
```

Y necesito convertirla en una tabla que para intervalos diarios de media hora cuente el número de **in**, **out** y **near**; tal que así:

```
interval            qt_in qt_out qt_near
2019-10-02 08:30:00 1     0      2 
2019-10-02 09:00:00 1     1      5
2019-10-02 09:30:00 2     0      3
```

Es decir, necesito saber la cantidad de entradas, salidas y aproximaciones para cada día en tramos de media hora; es posible que haya registros en cualquier tramo, sea el [00:00 - 00:30], el [12:00 - 12:30] o el [23:30 - 24:00].

*Comienzo de la edición:*

Ahora mismo tengo esto:

```
SELECT
    from_unixtime((unix_timestamp(in_time) DIV (60 * 30)) * (30 * 60)) AS interval_in,
    sum(CASE WHEN in_time IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS qt_in
    FROM count_config_module.ap_summary
        GROUP BY 
            interval_in
        ORDER BY interval_in
        ;
```

Consultas análogas para **out** y **near** arrojan los resultados que espero para cada campo fecha, pero ahora necesitaría juntarlo todo en una misma tabla con un campo de intervalos temporales común procedente de... ¿alguna de ellas? ¿De todas? ¿De ninguna?

Hay muchos más **near** que **in** y **out**, aunque a veces haya **in** y **out** sin **near**, por lo que es muy posible que absolutamente todos los intervalos necesarios para **in** y **out** estén ya presentes en **near**.

Con esto consigo el campo común de intervalos que quiero:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT from_unixtime((unix_timestamp(in_time) DIV (60 * 30)) * (30 * 60)) AS interval_all
    FROM count_config_module.ap_summary
UNION
SELECT
    DISTINCT from_unixtime((unix_timestamp(out_time) DIV (60 * 30)) * (30 * 60))
    FROM count_config_module.ap_summary
UNION
SELECT
    DISTINCT from_unixtime((unix_timestamp(near_time) DIV (60 * 30)) * (30 * 60))
    FROM count_config_module.ap_summary
;
```

Sin embargo, no veo forma de sacarle provecho...

*Fin de la edición.*

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que has intentado

Comment: He creado un SQL Fiddle con tus datos para poder reproducir tu problema: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/48XtmV71nhm5W61ZZzRaCm/0

Comment: ¿Podría editarlo? Así le añado más datos que los que puse de ejemplo.

Comment: ¡Claro! Cada revisión agrega un número a la URL. Por cierto, agregué los ejemplos que pusiste en la edición :) Ya estoy de vuelta, así que intentaré echarle un vistazo al problema

Comment: ¿Te importa si uso una [tabla temporal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html) para reducir la profundidad de la consulta anidada? Las tablas temporales sólo son visibles por la conexión en curso y se eliminan automáticamente al cerrar la conexión.

Comment: Por supuesto, Óscar, lo que necesites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución podría ser la siguiente:

```
-- Buscamos los campos que están entre los rangos de fecha
SELECT
  interval_bajo intervalo,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN in_time BETWEEN interval_bajo AND interval_alto
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) in_time,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN out_time BETWEEN interval_bajo AND interval_alto
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) out_time,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN near_time BETWEEN interval_bajo AND interval_alto
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) near_time
FROM (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT FROM_UNIXTIME(interval_all) interval_bajo,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(interval_all + (60 * 30) - 1) interval_alto
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(in_time) DIV (60 * 30)) * (60 * 30) AS interval_all
    FROM ap_summary
    UNION
    SELECT
      DISTINCT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(out_time) DIV (60 * 30)) * (60 * 30)
    FROM ap_summary
    UNION
    SELECT
      DISTINCT (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(near_time) DIV (60 * 30)) * (60 * 30)
    FROM ap_summary
  ) tabla_intermedia
  WHERE interval_all IS NOT NULL
) ap_summary_temp
INNER JOIN ap_summary
GROUP BY interval_bajo
```

Me baso en una subconsulta como la que creaste tú, pero sin convertir en fecha, llamada `ap_summary_temp`. En ella luego obtengo las fechas no repetidas (podrían repetirse entre campos) al tiempo que calculo la fecha y hora de comienzo del rango y el final.

Por último repaso todos los registros de la tabla `ap_summary_temp` comparando cada uno con cada registro de la subconsulta anterior, para sumar `1` (igual que hiciste en tu ejemplo) si cada campo está dentro del rango.

Es probable que la consulta se pueda optimizar considerablemente, pero al menos funciona sin complicar en exceso el código.

Puedes probar el [resultado en línea en este enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/48XtmV71nhm5W61ZZzRaCm/2).

El resultado para tus datos de entrada sería:

```
intervalo           in_time out_time near_time
2019-10-02 09:30:00   0        0         1
2019-10-02 10:30:00   1        0         0
2019-10-02 11:30:00   0        0         1
2019-10-02 12:00:00   1        1         0
2019-10-02 12:30:00   0        1         0
```

Comment: PD: Me acabo de dar cuenta que está contando duplicados algunos valores, voy a investigar el motivo.

Comment: Estaba con otra movida en el curro, le echo un ojo. Muchas gracias, Óscar.

Comment: Lo primero que he hecho es probar tu consulta sin mirar nada más sobre mi base de datos y creo que salen exactamente los resultados esperados. Ayer me había preparado un Excel con una combinación de mis tres consultas individuales y los números concuerdan y lo hacen en los intervalos que deben.

Comment: Ahh, ¡vale! ¡¡Ya sé por qué me salen mal las cuentas en mis pruebas!! Verás que en el fiddle que compartí repetí dos veces el primer registro :) Ya lo he corregido y funciona bien, voy a editar mi respuesta para enlazar al fiddle correcto.

Comment: PD: En el fiddle te compartí también cómo hacerlo con una tabla temporal.

Comment: Muy buena solución, Óscar, muchas gracias por todo.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿cómo es posible el `INNER JOIN` con `ap_summary` sin especificar entre qué parámetros hacerlo? Porque, claro, los atributos de `ap_summary_temp` no existen en `ap_summary`...

Comment: Es como una convolución, cada registro de una tabla se relaciona con un registro de la otra, permitiendo que cada registro sea comparado con cada rango de fechas. Un `FROM` de ambas tablas (la generada por la subconsulta y la real) hubiera funcionado igual, pero lo dejé así para separarlo claramente.