# MySQL: Obtener tabla con intervalos temporales comunes a partir de dos tablas diferentes

Tags: mysql, sql

[MySQL: Obtener tabla con intervalos 30minutales a partir de otra con fechas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/299849/mysql-obtener-tabla-con-intervalos-30minutales-a-partir-de-otra-con-fechas)

A partir de la solución expuesta en el enlace, he intentado crear otra consulta en la que en vez de combinar tres atributos (`in_time`, `out_time` y `near_time`) de una misma tabla (`ap_summary`) se combine el mismo (`summary_time`) de dos tablas diferentes (`camera_summary` e `ir_summary`).

Estas tablas ya vienen en el formato que deseo, por lo que no hay que hacer transformaciones de fechas a intervalos 30minutales; sólo quiero combinarlas para obtener una única consulta que junte datos de cámaras e infrarrojos, ya que ahora estoy utilizando una consulta diferente para cada tipo de dispositivo.

Por pasos:

```
    SELECT
        DISTINCT interval_both AS interval_low
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT summary_time AS interval_both FROM camera_summary
                UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT summary_time FROM ir_summary
        ) AS table_1
        WHERE interval_both IS NOT NULL
        ;
```

Esto da como resultado una tabla con los intervalos, tal que así:

```
interval_low
2019-07-15 17:00:00
2019-07-15 17:30:00
2019-07-15 18:00:00
2019-07-15 18:30:00
2019-07-15 19:00:00
```

El problema viene al intentar relacionar esta tabla temporal con `camera_summary`:

```
    SELECT 
        interval_low AS summary_time,
        cs.in_counter AS qt_in_c,
        cs.out_counter AS qt_out_c
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                DISTINCT interval_both AS interval_low
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT summary_time AS interval_both FROM camera_summary
                    UNION
                    SELECT DISTINCT summary_time FROM ir_summary
                ) AS table_1
                WHERE interval_both IS NOT NULL
        ) AS table_2
            INNER JOIN camera_summary AS cs
        ;
```

Ya que los resultados son los esperados para las mediciones que hacen las cámaras, pero el intervalo temporal se repite una y otra vez:

```
 summary_time        qt_in_c qt_out_c
 2019-07-15 17:00:00 24      25
 2019-07-15 17:00:00 15      16
 2019-07-15 17:00:00 5       15
 2019-07-15 17:00:00 5       6
 2019-07-15 17:00:00 4       5
```

Si además se intenta relacionar con `ir_summary`:

```
    SELECT 
        interval_low AS summary_time,
        cs.in_counter AS qt_in_c,
        cs.out_counter AS qt_out_c,
        irs.in_counter AS qt_in_ir,
        irs.out_counter AS qt_out_ir
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                DISTINCT interval_both AS interval_low
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT summary_time AS interval_both FROM camera_summary
                    UNION
                    SELECT DISTINCT summary_time FROM ir_summary
                ) AS table_1
                WHERE interval_both IS NOT NULL
        ) AS table_2
            INNER JOIN camera_summary AS cs
            INNER JOIN ir_summary AS irs
        ;
```

La situación empeora, ya que los resultados son los esperados para los infrarrojos, pero se pasa a repetir el primer registro para las cámaras:

```
summary_time        qt_in_c qt_out_c qt_in_ir qt_out_ir
2019-07-15 17:00:00 24      25       8        10
2019-07-15 17:00:00 24      25       7        6
2019-07-15 17:00:00 24      25       21       11
2019-07-15 17:00:00 24      25       11       10
2019-07-15 17:00:00 24      25       13       8
2019-07-15 17:00:00 24      25       3        2
```

Gracias por adelantado por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Intuyo que pudiera ser algún problema de agrupación, y que por eso repite siempre el primer registro, pero he estado haciendo pruebas y ninguna ha sido satisfactoria, porque aunque agrupe `interval_low`, el resto de parámetros, que son cantidades de personas registradas por los dispositivos, ya vienen agrupadas por intervalos en la propia base de datos, con lo cual hacer `sum()` devuelve resultados ridículos.

Answer (score 1):

Partiendo que el pivote es la *tabla derivada* de intervalos:

1. Te falta la condición del JOIN, un `JOIN` sin `ON` resulta en un `CROSS JOIN` el cual multiplica los registros.
2. Debería ser un OUTER JOIN, a menos que estés seguro que para cada intervalo existe por lo menos un registro en ambas tablas.
3. El agrupamiento por intervalo podría no ser necesario dependiendo de los datos, pero es más seguro ponerlo.

```
SELECT t.interval_both AS summary_time
     , sum(cs.in_counter) AS qt_in_c
     , sum(cs.out_counter) AS qt_out_c
     , sum(irs.in_counter) AS qt_in_ir
     , sum(irs.out_counter) AS qt_out_ir
  FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT summary_time AS interval_both FROM camera_summary WHERE summary_time IS NOT NULL
         UNION
         SELECT DISTINCT summary_time FROM ir_summary WHERE summary_time IS NOT NULL
       ) AS t
    LEFT JOIN camera_summary AS cs
      ON cs.summary_time = t.interval_both
    LEFT JOIN ir_summary AS irs
      ON irs.summary_time = t.interval_both
  GROUP BY t.interval_both
```

Comment: El primer `LEFT JOIN` con `camera_summary` parece funcionar bien, salen 12 registros más que haciendo un simple `SELECT * FROM camera_summary`, porque hay 12 intervalos de IRs sin datos de cámaras; sin embargo, al añadir el segundo `LEFT JOIN`, con `ir_summary`, el resultado se descontrola y aparecen una burrada de registros (creo que se pone a multiplicar, como si fuera un `CROSS JOIN`). Todo esto sin agrupar por `t.interval_both`. Si agrupas sale un número coherente de resultados, el equivalente al número que existe de intervalos, pero algunos sumatorios de cámaras e IRs salen altísimos.